# Is it possible to create Windows Service Applications with C++/WinRT?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services, c++-winrt

I am designing a new Windows Service Application and I would like to know if modern C++/WinRT can be used to build a binary executable conforming to the interface rules of the Service Control Manager (SCM).

Comment: I have written many services in plain C++, not in WinRT.

Comment: @rem: C++/WinRT *is* plain C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++/WinRT is routinely used within Windows services to access various Windows APIs so in that sense yes it certainly works. It does not however provide any support for actually implementing the Windows service API callbacks, but those are not hard to implement yourself. [Here's an example](https://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/Toward-Better-Design-in-Native-C_2B002B00_).

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lpservice_main_functiona) of ServiceMain:

> Minimum supported client  Windows XP [desktop apps only]
>
> Minimum supported server  Windows Server 2003 [desktop apps only]

If using Xaml Islands to include C++/WinRT inside a desktop application then it will work, but what is the point of all that anyway? Service applications cannot have a GUI, which eliminates the need of UWP or C++/WinRT.

WinRT is based on C++ 17 and you can very well use all C++ 17 features in the service application.

Comment: The GUI is just a *fraction* of the Windows Runtime API surface. The point of using C++/WinRT in a non-GUI process is to have access to the Windows Runtime with a safe and modern interface.